# C++ to call TASM to assemble .asm file into .com

Tags: c++, assembly, tasm

I am new to c++, could anyone point me to how can I write a c++ code which will call TASM to assemble the .asm file into a .com and execute it?

I've written a c++ code that compiles an input .cpp file into .asm file but could not see any online resource on how to invoke TASM to assemble the generated .asm file.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use the `system(char*)` library function to run external shell commands.  Or maybe a Windows specific one like CreateProcess, if you're writing for Windows.  Why is this tagged NASM?  Do you want an answer for it, too, or instead?

Comment: Thanks Peter! what external shell commands are these? sorry if I seem to naive

Comment: Commands like `tasm foo.asm`.  i.e. anything you could run from the command line.  Note that you can't execute a `.com` directly on a 64-bit OS.  If you happen to have a 32-bit version of Windows, you could run a `.com` under that.  Otherwise you'd either have to compile your C++ program to run inside DOSBox or something, or use command line args for DOSBox or BOCHS or something to get it to start a 16-bit virtual machine and run the `.com` after starting DOS.  So you really just need to go look up how to build and run TASM, then automate those commands from C++.

Comment: so more or less, the c++ code will be system(tasm foo.asm)? and will .obj work on a 64-bit instead of .com?

Comment: You should look into `_spawn()` or `_exec()` if they are available on your platform.

Comment: it's pretty unclear what you want to archive. perhaps writing a simple batchfile (compile step #1: create the .asm from your .cpp, compile step #2: assemble the .asm to a .com and (optionally) start it if the assemble worked) could serve you better (this could also be included into your C++ code via `system()`, tho it's not needed )

Comment: If you want to generate a COM file you will need to make sure you are using `.model tiny`. You will need to do `tasm foo.asm` and then link the object file to a .COM with `tlink /t foo.obj`. The generated file should be `foo.com`

Comment: COM program are DOS and will not run on as a 64-bit program

Comment: system() and spawn() works! thanks everyone